# AngularJS не сохраняет значения в базу

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, websocket, coffeescript

Никак не пойму, что я делаю не так. Проект на RoR (с WebSocketRails), верстка haml, angular и coffeescript. Angular не сохраняет данные.

Вот фрагмент страницы (haml):

```
    .form-group
      .col-xs-12
        %label.control-label Имя:
      .col-xs-12
        %input.form-control{'ng-model' => 'user_profile.first_name'}
    .form-group
      .col-xs-12
        %label.control-label Фамилия:
      .col-xs-12
        %input.form-control{'ng-model' => 'user_profile.last_name'}
    .form-group
      .col-xs-12
        %label.control-label skype:
      .col-xs-12
        %input.form-control{'ng-model' => 'user_profile.skype'}

    .button-group
      %button.button.btn.btn-cancel{'ng-click' => "cancel()"}
        Отмена
      %button.button.btn.btn-save{'ng-click' => 'save_user_profile()'}
        Сохранить
```

В соответствующем контроллере, описан метод сохранения профиля:

```
    @personal.controller 'PersonalAccountCtrl', ['$scope', 'Logging', 'SmipeData', ($scope, Logging, SmipeData) ->
      $scope.save_user_profile = () ->
        SmipeData.save_user_profile()
    ]
```

Который вызывает метод класса:

```
    @smipe.factory 'SmipeData', ['$http', '$rootScope', 'Logging', ($http, $rootScope, Logging) ->
    class SmipeData
      ...
      dispatcher = new WebSocketRails(websocket_url)
      ...
      save_user_profile: () ->
        dispatcher.trigger('smipe.edit', {user:user_profile}, save_user_profile_success, save_user_profile_failure)
```

Здесь dispatcher это экземпляр класса WebSocketRails (его я подключил установив гем "WebSocketRails").
Сам 'smipe.edit' в свою очередь это метод в контроллере:

```
    def edit
      if current_user and message.has_key? :user
        if current_user.update_profile(message[:user])
          @response[:success] = true
          @response[:user] = UserSerializer.new(current_user, root: false)
        else
          @response[:success] = false
        end
      end
      trigger_success @response
    end
```

После чего выполняется success callback из того же SmipeData:

```
    @smipe.factory 'SmipeData', ['$http', '$rootScope', 'Logging', ($http, $rootScope, Logging) ->
    class SmipeData
      ...
    save_user_profile_success = (data) ->
      if data.success
        $rootScope.$apply ->
          user_profile = data.user
      else
        console.log "save_user_profile error"
```

Собственно все. Но данные в базе не появились. Что я делаю не так?

Вроде как, эта строчка должна сохранить в базу:

```
    $rootScope.$apply ->
      user_profile = data.user
```

Но она не сохраняет.

Кто использовал Angular и WebSocket'ы подскажите пожалуйста как выполнить сохранение в базу данных. Или подскажите где почитать про angular и websocket.

P.S. База PostgreSQL, и она рабочая, конфиги корректные, devis'ом пользователи создаются. А вот как изменить их данные не пойму.

Comment: Откройте уже инструменты разработчика в вашем любимом браузере - и выясните, попадают данные на сервер или нет. После этого у вас пропадет половина вопроса - и с тем что получилось можно будет работать. Сейчас это не вопрос, а тест на выявление провидческих способностей.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.

Comment: А данные на сервер то уходят?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В контроллере вызывается метод `update_profile()` описанный в моделе User. Куда передаются все данные с формы `message[:user]`

```
if current_user.update_profile(message[:user])
```

Так вот валиация в `update_profile()` и не пропускала данные в базу.
Всем спасибо, что откликнулись.

P.S. а angular'овское `$apply`

```
$rootScope.$apply ->
       user_profile = data.user
```

Только лишь обновляет связанные данные в форме.